# Displaying empty message for a section in MergedAdapter

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm using a [MergedAdapter](https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-merge) to group two custom adapters (ArrayAdapter derived) along with a section header for each one into a single ListView. It is working fine, but now I need to display a TextView saying "No Data" for the section that has no items, e.g. ArrayAdapter is empty.

What's the best approach for this? The code that sets the ListView binding is like this:

```
ArrayList<ItemOne> firstItems = getFirstGroupItems();
ArrayList<ItemTwo> secondItems = getSecondGroupItems();

ItemOneAdapter firstAdapter = new ItemOneAdapter(this, this.firstItems);
ItemTwoAdapter secondAdapter = new ItemTwoAdapter(this, this.secondItems);

MergeAdapter adapter = new MergeAdapter();
adapter.addView(createGroupSeparator(R.string.first_section_header));  //Just creates a TextView
adapter.addAdapter(firstAdapter);
adapter.addView(createGroupSeparator(R.string.second_section_header)); //Just creates a TextView
adapter.addAdapter(secondAdapter);

listView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Answer (score 0):

In case of an empty list, you could make the first item read "No Data", but this usually makes the code unmanageable. I would suggest you add an invisible TextView to your screen with the message; this is only displayed when the list is empty.

Comment: For the whole list view being empty, I can do that, but I want to do that per each adapter I add to MergeAdapter.